# Is there a better way to remove all annotations from PDF document?

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, pdfkit

I need to remove all annotations from PDF document using PDFKit. 
Here is my solution:

This solution doesn't work for me, because in one case im getting exception when mutating array while iteration on it.

```
func removeAllAnnotations() {
        guard let documentCheck = document else { return }
        for i in (0..<documentCheck.pageCount) {
            if let page = documentCheck.page(at: i) {
                for annotation in page.annotations {
                    page.removeAnnotation(annotation)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to avoid the “mutate while iterating” problem, just create your own local copy of the array, and iterate through that:

```
func removeAllAnnotations() {
    guard let document = document else { return }

    for i in 0..<document.pageCount {
        if let page = document.page(at: i) {
            let annotations = page.annotations
            for annotation in annotations {
                page.removeAnnotation(annotation)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But, no, I don’t know of any better way to remove all annotations.

Comment: Thanks. But its about document pages array. And if I`ll iterate on its copy and there assign copy to main document, the scroll view will jump. This doesn't work for me, unfortunately

Comment: If you make copy of array of class objects, it’s just an array of class references. When you copy the array, it’s just a new array of references to the exact same class instances. It’s not going to cause any UI behaviors. E.g. take the above and comment out the call to `removeAnnotation`... does the scroll view jump around? If not, then it’s not the copying of the array that is causing your UI behavior. If you’re seeing the scrollview “jump”, it is likely just because the it’s observing changes to the underlying PDF document.

Comment: Try these alternatives without array copy and see if they manifest the same behavior. https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/20facda08e063dc3461e073f7c87206d

Comment: Unfortunately, Rob, nothing of this options helped. Same issue...

Comment: That’s my point. This behavior has nothing to do with the assigning copy of the array, as you suggested above. It’s apparently just what the PDFView does when you remove annotations. To prevent that you could temporarily remove the PDFView or overlay it with a [snapshot view](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622531-snapshotview) so you don’t see that jarring UX.

Answer (score 0):

This is the objective-C solution, I came up with. This function will not encounter the “mutate while iterating” crash! Hope this will be helpful to someone.

```
- (void)removeAllAnnotations {
    if (self.pdfDocument) {
        for (int i = 0; i < self.pdfDocument.pageCount; i++) {
            PDFPage *page = [self.pdfDocument pageAtIndex:i];
            PDFAnnotation *annotation = page.annotations.lastObject;
            while (annotation) {
                [page removeAnnotation:annotation];
                annotation = page.annotations.lastObject;
            }
        }
    }
}
```